# Logging into and scraping edline.net

Tags: python, authentication, web-scraping

So I have looked around for a bit and am struggling to scrape this website. I am attempting to do this with python and can't seem to log in. The website is https://www.edline.net/InterstitialLogin.page. If I could successfully log in and scrape that it would be very helpful.

Answer (score -1):

use selenium http://www.seleniumhq.org/ there is a python binding